# How to use objectContaining() or another method to assert that key/value pairs are in a request body in Jest

Tags: lightning-web-components, unit-test, lwc-jest

I am trying to assert that `currencyIsoCode: 'USD'` is in an HTTP request body. I am able to assert that `method: 'POST'` is in the request body, so I am assuming the problem has something to do with the nested object. I've already tried `expect.objectContaining({currencyIsocode: 'USD'})`, but this also does not work due to nesting I believe. If you have any suggestions, let me know. If you have another approach other than using `objectContaining()`, that would be great as well.

```
it('should pass currencyIsoCode if currencyIsoCode is present in context', async () => {
            (<jest.Mock>getInternalContext).mockResolvedValue({ currencyIsoCode: 'USD' });
            mockAccountId = '005000000000ABC';
            const mockFetch = <jest.Mock>fetch;
            mockFetch.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockProductPromotionalPricingCollectionResponseOk());
            const result = await readPromotionalPricingCollection(productData);
            expect(result).toEqual(getPromotionalPricingCollectionData());
            expect(mockFetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            expect(mockFetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
                `/services/data/${API_VERSION}/commerce/promotions/actions/evaluate-products`,
                expect.objectContaining({
                    body: expect.objectContaining({ currencyIsoCode: 'USD', }),
                })
            );
        });
```

Error:

```
Expected: "/services/data/v58.0/commerce/promotions/actions/evaluate-products", ObjectContaining {"body": ObjectContaining {"currencyIsoCode": "USD"}}
Received: "/services/data/v58.0/commerce/promotions/actions/evaluate-products", {"body": "{\"webstoreId\":\"0ZER00000004ZWc\",\"products\":[{\"productId\":\"prod2\",\"salesPrice\":\"80.00\"}],\"currencyIsoCode\":\"USD\"}", "credentials": "same-origin", "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"}, "method": "POST", "signal": {}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to Jsonify the search query:

```
it('should pass currencyIsoCode if currencyIsoCode is present in context', async () => {
            (<jest.Mock>getInternalContext).mockResolvedValue({ currencyIsoCode: 'USD' });
            mockAccountId = '005000000000ABC';
            const searchQuery = {
                webstoreId: '0ZER00000004ZWc',
                products: [{ productId: 'prod1', salesPrice: '60.00' }],
                currencyIsoCode: 'USD',
            };
            const mockFetch = <jest.Mock>fetch;
            mockFetch.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockProductPromotionalPricingCollectionResponseOk());
            const result = await readPromotionalPricingCollection(productData);
            expect(result).toEqual(getPromotionalPricingCollectionData());
            expect(mockFetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            expect(mockFetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
                `/services/data/${API_VERSION}/commerce/promotions/actions/evaluate-products`,
                expect.objectContaining({
                    body: JSON.stringify(searchQuery),
                })
            );
        });
```